# How can I prove the theorem of the continuity of probability in the decreasing case?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to show that $A_n \rightarrow A$ then $P(A_n) \rightarrow$ P(A) as $ n \rightarrow \infty $ but in the decreasing case.

Comment: Reduce it to the increasing case by looking at $B_n=A_1\setminus A_n$, which increases and that tends to $A_1\setminus A$. Then $P(A_1)-P(A_n)=P(A_1\setminus A_n)\to P(A_1\setminus A)=P(A_1)-P(A)$. Cancel the $P(A_1)$, multiply by $-1$ and you get that $P(A_n)\to P(A)$. When $P$ is not a probability, but a general measure, then one needs that $P(A_1)$, or at least some $P(A_k)$ is finite.

Answer (score 3):

Let $B_j = A_1\setminus A_j$, then $B_n\subset B_{n+1}$ , $P(B_1) = P(B_j) + P(A_j)$, and $$\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_j = A_1\setminus\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right).$$
By continuity from above, we then have
$$
P(A_1) = P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right) + \lim_{j\to\infty} P(B_j) = P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right) + \lim_{j\to\infty}(P(A_1)-P(A_j)).
$$
Since $P(A_1)<\infty$, we may subtract it from both sides to yield the desired result, $$P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right) = \lim_{j\to\infty} P(A_j).$$

Now since we used continuity from above, we need to prove it as well. Setting $A_0=\varnothing$, we have
$$
P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty P(A_j\setminus A_{j-1}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n P(A_j\setminus A_{j-1}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n).$$

Answer (score 0):

$1_{A_1}$ is integrable and $1_{A_n} \le 1_{A_1}$. Since $1_{A_n}(\omega) \to 1_A(\omega)$ we have $PA_n = \int 1_{A_n} dP \to \int 1_{A} dP = PA$.